# Asynchronous operation in ASP.NET MVC using a thread

Tags: asp.net-mvc, multithreading

We have asp.net mvc application, in which we have requirement to upload a large file of size more than 10MB , to accomplish this we created a thread which runs at background to insert records using sqlbulkcopy into database so that user need not to wait for long time.

It works well when we run this locally but when we deployed on test server, thread doesn't work.

Let me know if we need to do any setting in IIS 6.1 on test server to make it work.

Code as below :

```
Thread newThread = new Thread(() => loanResult1 = rep.filterSamplingLoans(dtLoans, model.ReviewId, (int)TempData["LoanCount"]));
    newThread.IsBackground = true;
    newThread.Start();
```

ajax code:

```
          $.ajax({
                url: '/ReviewSampleUpload/FilterSamplingLoans',
                async: true,

                success: function (data) {
                }
            });
```

ajax calling function with thread:

```
     public JsonResult FilterSamplingLoans()
    {
        if ((bool)TempData["FilterSamplingLoans"] == true)
        {
            TempData["FilterSamplingLoans"] = false;
        }
        System.Data.DataTable dtLoans = new System.Data.DataTable();
        dtLoans = (System.Data.DataTable)TempData["dtLoans"];
        System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch sw = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();
        SamplingLoanResults loanResult1 = SamplingLoanResults.ValidationInProcess;
        ReviewsRepository rep = new ReviewsRepository();
        Thread newThread = new Thread(() => loanResult1 = rep.filterSamplingLoans(dtLoans, (int)TempData["ReviewId"], (int)TempData["LoanCount"]));
        newThread.IsBackground = true;
        newThread.Start();
        //added this because of JIT exception when using multithreading,only when published we are getting this
        //The Just-In-Time debugger was launched without necessary security permissions
        newThread.Join(10);
        JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();

        return Json(JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

    }
```

ajax calling without thread :

```
     public JsonResult ProcessFileUpload()
    {
        JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        if ((bool)TempData["FilterSamplingLoans"] == true)
        {
            TempData["FilterSamplingLoans"] = false;
        }
        System.Data.DataTable dtLoans = new System.Data.DataTable();
        dtLoans = (System.Data.DataTable)TempData["dtLoans"];
        System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch sw = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();
        SamplingLoanResults loanResult1 = SamplingLoanResults.ValidationInProcess;
        ReviewsRepository rep = new ReviewsRepository();
        loanResult1 = rep.filterSamplingLoans(dtLoans, (int)TempData["ReviewId"], (int)TempData["LoanCount"]));

        return Json(JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

    }
```

File upload calling function :

```
         [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult FileUpload(ReviewSampleFileModel model)
    {
        var loanfileupload = e[ReviewStatusCode.LoanFileUploaded];
        ReviewsRepository rep = new ReviewsRepository();
        System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch sw = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();
        System.Data.DataTable dtValidLaons = new System.Data.DataTable();
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            //ReviewsRepository rep = new ReviewsRepository();
            System.Data.DataTable dtValidatedLaons = new System.Data.DataTable();
            string folderPath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ReviewSampleUploadPath"];
            int excelLoanCount = 0;
            // sw.Start();
            SamplingLoanResults loanResult = rep.SaveSamplingFile(model.ReviewId, model.File.FileName, model.File.InputStream, User.Identity.Name, folderPath, out dtValidatedLaons, out excelLoanCount);
            dtValidLaons = dtValidatedLaons;
            int totalExcelLoanCount = excelLoanCount;
            TempData["dtLoans"] = dtValidLaons;
            TempData["ReviewId"] = model.ReviewId;
            TempData["LoanCount"] = totalExcelLoanCount;
            SamplingLoanResults loanResult1 = SamplingLoanResults.Success;
            if (loanResult == SamplingLoanResults.Success)
            {
                TempData["Message"] = "File upload is under process, you will receive email once it is uploaded !";
            }

        else
        {
            TempData["Message"] = "Please check your inputs and try again !";
        }

        return View(model);
    }
```

onbeforeunload :

```
   window.onbeforeunload = confirmExit;
        function confirmExit() {

            $.ajax({
                url: '/ReviewSampleUpload/ProcessFileUpload',
                type: "POST",
                async: true,

                success: function (data) {
                }
            });
    }
```

Comment: @VamshiChilukuri you still haven't followed up on what I said: Capture exceptions and post them here. Until then we cannot help you. You can reopen after you have done that.

Answer (score 1):

The time spent by a request to upload a file is unavoidable.  The data has to be transferred to your server and this take times.  The time taken will depend on the speed of the processing of the file to the file system on the server and the connection speed between the uploading part and your server.

As for the processing locking the page.  You are performing your processing of the uploaded file `onbeforeunload`.  Of course this is going to lock the page up, or prevent the loading of the other page, because the processing is taking time and the page is waiting for the request to complete.  You can't have an AJAX request continue in the background when you have left the page.

If you need to process the file after the upload, and it takes more than a few seconds to complete, **this should not be performed within the ASP.NET MVC pipeline - this is not the kind of thing that ASP.NET MVC (or web pages for that matter) is designed to do**.  It should be processed within a Windows Service on the server, the status of which should be reported through your web page by means of a flag in the database to indicate that the processing is complete.